# WebApi is trying to load Owin while it's not in References

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dependencies

I'm making a double-layer WebApi and I made something wrong that I think linked my two projects together.

Now, my applicationServices (Internal WebApi) tries to load Owin even if it's not in References, neither in packages.config.
I don't know where it is specified to load Owin. The Error message I get is :

```
         <H1>Erreur du serveur dans l'application '/ApplicationServices'.
            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>
        </H1>
        <h2>
            <i>Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'Owin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5' ou une de ses d&#233;pendances. Le fichier sp&#233;cifi&#233; est introuvable.</i>
        </h2>
```

(For those who don't understand french : Unable to load file or assembly Owin or one of his dependencies, can't find the file)

My packages.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="FluentNHibernate" version="2.0.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Iesi.Collections" version="4.0.0.4000" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.0.6" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.fr" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.fr" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.fr" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.fr" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.fr" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.fr" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.fr" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.6" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NHibernate" version="4.1.1.4000" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

My references :

[image]

And my Web.Config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="time_format" value="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.4000" newVersion="4.1.0.4000" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

I thought that it was because I accidentaly linked my two projects (the one who uses Owin and this one) by making both of them call the same Class Library...

I don't know what to do, can you please help me ?

Comment: Have you tried removing the bin and obj folders

Comment: It works !! Thank you very much, you should post the answer so I would be able to mark your answer solved my problem with explications ? :D

Comment: Thank you for the reminder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the obj and the bin folders, some old owin dll may be left from a previous build.